# Can we have DataContractSerializer, XMLFormatSerializer both in same service(ServiceContract) for different methods(OperationContract)?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

Code:

```
        public interface IServices
        {
        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        GetProductsResponse Getproducts(GetProductsRequest productsrequest);

        [OperationContract]
        SaveProductsResponse SaveProducts1(SaveProductsRequest1 productsrequest);
        }     

        [DataContract]
        public class SaveProductsRequest1
        {
            [DataMember]
            public List<Person> Persons;
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Person
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int Id;
        }
```

Client :

```
    ServicesClient client = new ServicesClient();
    SaveProductsRequest1 req = new SaveProductsRequest1();
    req.Persons = new List<Person> { new Person { Id = 10 } }.ToArray();
    client.SaveProducts1(req);
```

I am invoking the `SaveProducts1` call from client side and not able to get the value '10' in my service side(seems deserialization issue). But when I remove `[XmlSerializerFormat]` attribute from `Getproducts` call, it just works fine and I am able to see the value 10.

Why is it happening(Why SaveProducts1 depends on Getproducts OperationContract)? What workaround I should provide, when I want to use both xml and datacontract serialization? Any help appreciated.

Note: I have very updated proxy. I am not seeing any issue in proxy. Even I tried with one sample and getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh your client service reference after adding the `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute?  It could be that the contracts don't match any longer.